# How to change the color of a path on click in custom painter

Tags: flutter, svg

I have this code that draws a world map on the custom painter with the help of the SVG data. I'm successfully able to complete the drawing part but how do I change the color of a path when it is clicked? I can listen to click events of different paths differently using TouchyCanvas.

Here is the code that paints the paths from the data map:

```
// drawing the paths
    for (String key in mapData.keys) {
      Path path = parseSvgPathData(mapData[key]!);

      touchyCanvas.drawPath(
        path,
        Paint()
          ..color = Colors.black
          ..strokeWidth = 1
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
        onTapUp: (details) {
          // TODO: handle how to paint the tapped area
        },
      );
    }
```

Here is the complete code:
https://pastebin.com/7WZF3gQy

Comment: I still can't figure out how to highlight the tapped area

Comment: @pskink nvm. Got it figured out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by keeping the state of the tapped path in the parent of the custom painter.

Here is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_drawing/path_drawing.dart';
import 'package:touchable/touchable.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Path? selected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build called');
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          child: CanvasTouchDetector(
            gesturesToOverride: const [GestureType.onTapUp],
            builder: (context) {
              return CustomPaint(
                size: const Size(2000, double.infinity),
                painter: MyPainter(context, selected, (Path path) {
                  selected = path;
                  setState(() {});
                }),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final BuildContext context;
  final Path? selected;
  final Function(Path path) handler;
  MyPainter(this.context, this.selected, this.handler);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    print('paint called');
    TouchyCanvas touchyCanvas = TouchyCanvas(context, canvas);

    final Map<String, String> mapData = {
      '0':
          'M1383 261.6l1.5 1.8-2.9 0.8-2.4 1.1-5.9 0.8-5.3 1.3-2.4 2.8 1.9 2.7 1.4 3.2-2 2.7 0.8 2.5-0.9 2.3-5.2-0.2 3.1 4.2-3.1 1.7-1.4 3.8 1.1 3.9-1.8 1.8-2.1-0.6-4 0.9-0.2 1.7-4.1 0-2.3 3.7 0.8 5.4-6.6 2.7-3.9-0.6-0.9 1.4-3.4-0.8-5.3 1-9.6-3.3 3.9-5.8-1.1-4.1-4.3-1.1-1.2-4.1-2.7-5.1 1.6-3.5-2.5-1 0.5-4.7 0.6-8 5.9 2.5 3.9-0.9 0.4-2.9 4-0.9 2.6-2-0.2-5.1 4.2-1.3 0.3-2.2 2.9 1.7 1.6 0.2 3 0 4.3 1.4 1.8 0.7 3.4-2 2.1 1.2 0.9-2.9 3.2 0.1 0.6-0.9-0.2-2.6 1.7-2.2 3.3 1.4-0.1 2 1.7 0.3 0.9 5.4 2.7 2.1 1.5-1.4 2.2-0.6 2.5-2.9 3.8 0.5 5.4 0z',
    };

    // drawing the paths
    for (String key in mapData.keys) {
      Path path = parseSvgPathData(mapData[key]!);

      // drawing all the paths
      touchyCanvas.drawPath(
        path,
        Paint()
          ..color = Colors.black
          ..strokeWidth = 1
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
        onTapUp: (details) {
          handler(path);
        },
      );
    }

    // if there is a selected path then draw it
    if (selected != null) {
      touchyCanvas.drawPath(selected!, Paint()..color = Colors.red);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the particular reason of using that `TouchyCanvas` if you can do that much better with standard flutter widgets?

Comment: I'm using TouchyCanvas to draw paths on custom painters that are scrollable. TouchyCanvas gives me the power to listen for clicks on scrollable paths.

Comment: Thank you so much @pskink. I couldn't open the SVG directly with the path object so I had some help from here https://stackoverflow.com/q/75418461/11283915. Other than that it is working seamlessly. I guess I will build upon this now :)

Comment: check https://gist.github.com/pskink/afd4f20a40ae7756555877ec030daa46#file-world_map_2-dart - this has some added initial animations made in `_initController` method, also `world.svg` is taken from "normal" asset file: `final xml = await rootBundle.loadString('world.svg');`

Comment: @pskink Is there any way I can prevent the paint() method from re-running if the only thing I do is scroll the screen? Because when I'm scrolling the screen horizontally, it seems to be lagging.

Comment: btw tried to run it in `release` (not in `debug`) mode? more here: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes#release

Comment: @pskink Just a last question (most probably). How do I set the padding around the map? e.g. right now the map is touching the corners (https://imgur.com/a/PMNmG8K), so I want to add padding such that even after zooming the map, e.g. the left padding is only shown when I reach the end of the map while scrolling to the left.

Comment: @pskink I'm not setting a fill color, only setting the stroke and that too a light stroke. It seems to be working fine

Comment: add `Padding` as a parent of `SizedBox.fromSize`

Comment: Not working properly. set the padding as 50 for all the sides and it is cutting the map.

Comment: added 20 px padding: https://gist.github.com/pskink/afd4f20a40ae7756555877ec030daa46

Comment: @pskink the BoxFit.fitHeight seems to be allowing only the map size to fit in the height. It doesn't consider the padding. So when using BoxFit.fitHeight, it expands the map height as of the parent height but as it doesn't consider the padding, it makes that map scrollable for that padding. Is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: It seems like it has a default padding of 20 now and it fits perfectly for ```BoxFit.fitHeight``` but still if I set custom padding of like 10 to the parent ```Container``` of the ```SizedBox``` then the vertical scrolling appears for that value of 10. I just want to know if that is the intended behavior because I'm okay with this one as well.

Comment: honestly I don't know what `BoxFit.fitHeight` you mean as I don't use it anywhere in my code, if you want to change the padding change `final padding = ...` line then

Comment: I was talking about the ```sizeToRect()``` method where we expect an optional argument of type ```BoxFit``` and then we call this function inside the ```_initController()``` method and this is where I was passing the value to this optional parameter as ```BoxFit.fitHeight```. But never mind, changing the padding at the specified line works just fine. I didn't notice it earlier. Thank you a ton for sticking with me throughout this :)

Comment: i switched from `Stack` to `Flow` widget - now it is much faster as only visible countries are drawn (it speeds up especially when you zoom in and only few countries are shown) - the selection is done here https://gist.github.com/pskink/afd4f20a40ae7756555877ec030daa46#file-world_map_2-dart-L166

Comment: @pskink using the updated one. Looks good :)

Comment: It is not lagging while scrolling but lagging while zooming in and out.

Comment: This (https://pub.dev/packages/countries_world_map) package seems to be doing great for zooming and scrolling purposes.