# File object not opening a local file in a flutter project but works in a dart file not part of the flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, file

So I want to open an SVG file in my `main.dart` file and for that, I'm using the File class and the `readAsStringSync()` method. But it seems like the File object cannot open the file.

And when I try to do the same thing outside of the flutter project, it seems to be working fine.

**Here is the folder structure that I'm using in both the flutter project and the dart project.**

```
lib
  |_ main.dart
  |_ world.svg
```

[image]

**Here is the main.dart of the flutter project:**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final xml = File('world.svg').readAsStringSync();

    print(xml);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Testing')),
    );
  }
}
```

**Error**

[image]

**And here is the main.dart of the dart project:**

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  String file = File('world.svg').readAsStringSync();

  print(file.length);
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: In android, you have to find the directory. Check the documentation here https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: You need to include the `.svg` file as an [*asset*](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images).  Otherwise, that file will live only in the *source tree* of your development system and will not be bundled with your compiled application that gets installed on the target device.

Comment: @SagarV Does that also apply if you just want to read the file from your code base?

Comment: @jamesdlin I tried adding it in the ```yaml``` file but still the same error

Comment: You can't just add the file to your `pubspec.yaml` file; you also have to change the way that you *load* the file.  Did you read the asset documentation that I linked to?  You need to use an `AssetBundle`.